# PHPDOC Abstract class does not insert extended class type <T> into methods returns

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, phpdoc

I've got following code:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @template T
 */
abstract class A {

    /**
     * @return T
     */
    public function read() {
        // return statement 
    }
}

class C {}

/**
 * @extends A<C>
 */
class B extends A {}

$b = new B();
$b->read();
```

Inside VSCode, when i hover over read method, i would like it to return `C` class back from method, currently comes `@return T` - it ignores `@extends A<C>` value.

I know there's a way to achieve this with `@method`, but It also makes doubled hints about a function if i declare it below `@template T`, and method declaration needs to be changed at 2 places if something changes.

Is it possible to achieve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As i realized right now, it works well. It didn't worked in my Code, because of declared class-string annotation, which seemed to override `T` value from `@extends`.

```php
    /**
     * @var class-string<T> $className
     */
    private string $className;
```

After defining it as normal `string` property, just for use case in class, method returns right object.